# How to work conditional razor template c#

Tags: c#, templates, razor

i was trying this code but getting error at run time. i want if IsUPS has true value then a new table row & table data will be added to table if IsUPS is false then table will have one table row and data? how to achieve this with razor template? please guide. thanks

```
    string template = "<table><tr><td>This is my sample template, 
    Hello @Model.Name!</td></tr> @if (@Model.IsUPS) {<tr><td> it is ups</td></tr> } 
    </table>";

    string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World", IsUPS = true });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly:** I believe that an error produces a following statement:

```
@if (@Model.IsUPS)
```

it should rather be:

```
@if (Model.IsUPS)
```

after first `@` you should put server-side code, so another `@` is not neccessary when writing condition.

**Secondly:** Is the template pasted in one-line? If not, you need to use verbatim string:

```
string template = @"<table><tr><td>This is my sample template, 
                    Hello @Model.Name!</td></tr> @if (Model.IsUPS) {<tr><td> it is ups</td></tr> } 
                    </table>";
```

**Thirdly:** show us an error you get. Are you using `RazorEngine` library?

**Fourth:** after my fixes that code should work, checked myself.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your "string result =" line works correctly;

There's quite a few things I would do differently here.

The error message (you should really have shared what the error is), related to your use of "@".

Try this:

```
@{
string template = @"<table><tr><td>This is my sample template, Hello" + this.Model.Name + @"!</td></tr>";

if (true)
{
    template += @"<tr><td> it is ups</td></tr>";
}

template += @"</table>";
}
```

The "@{ }" block encapsulates the html in a razor block so the use of @ for razor changes. Please note I have made the strings use @"" rather than "" so that if you want to split the html between lines you won't need to have string concatenation.